# Node.js fires callback twice, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the following code, why does the createFile callback fire twice? This only happens when the server (below) is processing two or more requests at the same time, not if only one request has been made. Output at the bottom of the post. The client making the request is not a browser, but another node.js script iterating through a directory and sending a http post request with the file to the server. The request is created like this:

```
fs.createReadStream(fileName).pipe(httprequest(options, function(error, response, body) { }));
```

```
function myRequest(request, response) {
  function writeFile(filePath, request, callback) {
    newFilePath = "/home/pi/upload"+filePath; //filePath looks like this: /home/blah/file.txt, the code below creates this structure under another directory, so newFilePath becomes /home/pi/upload/home/blah/file.txt
    tempFileName = path.basename(filePath)+".temp";
    console.log("Processing "+filePath+"->"+newFilePath+" with tempname " +tempFileName);
    var createFile = request.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tempFileName));
    createFile.on("finish", function(error) { //Why does it fire the callback twice?
      if(error) {
        throw error;
      } else {
        moveFile(tempFileName, newFilePath, function(error) {
          if(error) {
            throw error;
          } else {
            console.log("OK");
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  function moveFile(tempFileName, newFilePath, callback) {
    dirPath = path.dirname(newFilePath);
    fs.stat(dirPath, function(error, stats) { //check if dir exists
      if(error == null) {
        console.log(dirPath+" already exists");
        fs.stat(tempFileName, function(error, stats) { //check if file exists
          if(error == null) {
            console.log("OK, writing "+newFilePath);
            fs.rename(tempFileName, newFilePath, function(error) {
              if(error) { //Error on the second run, because the file has been moved in the first run, shouldn't happen?
                throw error;
              } else {
                var myCB = JSON.stringify({fMove: "OK"});
                callback(myCB);
              }
            });
          } else {
            console.log("File exists");
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
  writeFile(fileName, request, function() {
    //Do some stuff
  });
  request.on("end", function() {
    //Do other stuff
  }
});

http.createServer(myRequest).listen(8888);
```

Output from my script

```
Processing /home/pi/app/temp/client.js->/home/pi/upload/home/pi/app/temp/client.js with tempname client.js.temp
/home/pi/upload/home/pi/app/temp already exists
/home/pi/upload/home/pi/app/temp already exists
OK, Writing /home/pi/upload/home/pi/app/temp/client.js
OK, Writing /home/pi/upload/home/pi/app/temp/client.js

/home/pi/app/server.js:67
            throw error;
                  ^
{"fMove":"OK"}
```

Comment: You're not prefixing a bunch of variables with `var`, so they become global variables and get overwritten with each call.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I changed the code so the variables don't get overwritten, but unfortunately that didn't change the outcome.

Comment: Instead of editing to say solved you should just write an answer for your own question. Then wait however long it makes you wait to accept your own answer. If nobody else writes a better answer then mark yours as correct. It helps a lot for people using Google in the future.

Comment: @sacredheart while it's nice that you inform us that you have solved your question so that we don't waste our time, this is not the format exercised by Stackoverflow. Please create an answer containing your solution and remove the "SOLVED" portion from the title of your answer.

Comment: Sorry guys, new to this. I have added my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrect error handling made the script faulty.

In the moveFile function this part was wrong:

```
fs.rename(tempFileName, newFilePath, function(error) {
              if(error) {
                throw error;
              } else {
                var myCB = JSON.stringify({fMove: "OK"}); 
                callback(myCB); // <-- Malformatted callback! Should be callback(null, myCB);
              }
```

Which made this part of writeFile trigger on error and for some reason run twice:

```
moveFile(tempFileName, newFilePath, function(error) { //Should be moveFile(tempFileName, newFilePath, function(error, status) {
          if(error) {
            throw error;
          } else {
            console.log("OK");
          }
        });
```

When I fixed my code so it handles the error correctly, it works as intended!